# Formulário (Dividio em 6 passos) e preciso de um drag and drop de imagens num dos passos

Tags: php, javascript, upload

Estou a desenvolver um página WEB em que o utilizador tem de preencher o formulário e depois no final enviar-me todas as informações para que a minha empresa possa orçamentar o pedido dele.

O formulário está divido em 6 passos:
1º - Algumas informações da empresa;
2º - Os menus que vao ser utilizados;
3º - **Um Drag and Drop de imagens**
4º - **Um Drag and Drop de ficheiros de texto**
etc...
**ÁREA DRAG AND DROP**

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
<span>Arrastar e soltar ou clique aqui</span>
<div id="uploads"></div>
</div>
```

Ou seja, primeiro o utilizador carrega e mostra as fotos dentro da area de Drag and Drop. Depois no final do formulário, no botão de Enviar, preciso de um script (PHP acho eu), que me crie uma pasta dentro do servidor com o nome da Empresa(para ter uma melhor organização) e faça upload para dentro da mesma de todas as imagens ou ficheiros carregados pelo utilizador. Depois a parte de guardas as informaçoes na base de dados já nao é problema mas eu nao fiz essa parte pois preciso de ter a certeza que a parte "mais dificil" funciona que é o upload. Não tenho mesmo nenhum código feito , tentei algumas coisas , como o dropzone e alguns que encontrei na internet mas nao consegui implementar nenhum... Acho que o meu grande problema mesmo está em conseguir que quando carregar no butao de enviar conseguir gerar a pasta e fazer o upload dos ficheiros todos para ela.

Agradeço qualquer ajuda, obrigado.

**WEBSITE** 
http://www.addupsports.com/projeto/projeto/

Comment: Olá gotcha, acredito que a implementação da sua necessidade utilizando o dropzone.js é possível. Conforme verifiquei, acredito que este tutorial possa te ajudar: https://github.com/enyo/dropzone/wiki/Combine-normal-form-with-Dropzone só vai faltar a criação de diretórios no backend, mas uma das suas necessidades pode ser sanada.

Comment: Vou tentar fazer entao configurar o dropzone e testar a parte que carrega e mostra as imagens. Depois tenho de fazer um codigo em PHP para poder gerar a pasta com o nome da Empresa e fazer upload dos ficheiros certo ?

Comment: Exatamente gotcha, o dropzone apenas vai se encarregar da "dropzone" e exibir os arquivos selecionados e aquele tutorial ensina a configurar ele para não fazer upload automático Então, depois você só terá o trabalho de fazer o backend em php, que receberá os dados e os arquivos, que precisarão ser tratados (validados) e armazenados :)

Comment: Okei , agora eu consigo ter por onde me guiar. Eu já consegui por a area de drag and drop do dropzone mas agora para configura lo tenho de usar o Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone certo? em que ficheiro tenho de por esse excerto de código?

Comment: Para ele funcionar (sem configurar de acordo com aquele tutorial ainda), é baixar o JS dele do site oficial (dropzonejs.com) e adicionar ele em sua página (<script src="./path/to/dropzone.js"></script>); Após, adicione um form com a classe ("dropzone") e um input file com name ("file"); Carregue a página e faça um teste para ver se o dropzone funciona, após isso, siga aquele tutorial para ele não enviar arquivos automaticamente. Mais detalhes de instalação no site oficial....

Comment: Depois, aquelas configurações do tutorial você adiciona em algum arquivo javascript que você já carrega na página, ou, pode ser adicionado na mão mesmo, na página..., você escolhe a opção que melhor lhe agrada.

Comment: Pois , só há um problema, nao posso usar o <form> para o upload das imagens pois , o formulario é maior , ou seja o formulario envolve outras coisas , incluindo os dois uploads ... nao sabe se há forma de usar o dropzone numa div por exemplo ? assim consegui ter duas areas e fazer upload dos ficheiros das duas areas para a mesma pasta dps gerada. 
Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda.

Comment: Pode sim, é só escolher a div e adicionar a classe ("dropzone") se não estou enganado; Se não funcionar, você pode usar o exemplo da documentação oficial: // Dropzone class:
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", { url: "/file/post"}); No seu caso, não vai ter url, pq ele vai ser configurado para não fazer upload automático.

Comment: Eu vou tentar me guiar pelas suas instruções, vou tentar fazer o melhor que conseguir... Não o quero incomodar mais pois também não é meu "criado" :) mas muito obrigado pela sua ajuda e continue o seu bom trabalho.

Comment: Sem problemas, qualquer dúvida é só avisar.

Comment: Qual é a melhor forma de o contactar em caso de alguma duvida?

Comment: Pode chamar aqui mesmo, ou criar uma sala de chat e me adicionar; ou pode mandar um e-mail (rafaelwithoeft@gmail.com);

Comment: Assim o farei, mais uma vez obrigado :)